# How do you justify formally that geometry of sphere converges to euclidean geometry?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I have found a statement which says that if a geometric property holds for $S_r^{n-1}$ spheres of radious $r$, for every positive radious, then it holds for $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. For me, this is intuitively true, as bigger spheres tend to be flat, as euclidean spaces. However, I am looking for a formal way to say this. Is that someting on inner product of $(n-1)-$sphere of radious r converges to inner product in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ if $r$ goes to infinity or something like that? I'm not an expert in geometry. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does that statement include a definition of "geometric property"?  I would consider that statement to be totally wrong if "geometric property" is just given its ordinary informal meaning.

Comment: There are various senses in which you can say that $S_r^{n-1}$ "converges" to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ as $r\to\infty$, but none of those senses would make your statement true in any reasonable sense.

Comment: In the bottom of page 1 of this article https://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/1658.pdf I found that claim

Comment: Ah, OK, so the claim is not about an _arbitrary_ "geometric property" but about one very specific property (namely, Theorem 1.A).